# NSData base64Encode return nil swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64

i tryed

```
let contents = results["contents"] as! String!
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: contents, 
options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions())
let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)





let contents = results["contents"] as! String!
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: contents, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)



let contents = results["contents"] as! String!
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: contents, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)!)
let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

always EXC_BAC_INSTRUCTION from decodedString
maybe decodedData return nil

why NSData return nil

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Encoding64CharacterLineLength` as option, and apply `.base64EncodedStringWithOptions` to the data:

```
if let contents = results["contents"] as? String,
        decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: contents, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
    let decodedString = decodedData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using so many force unwrap operators (`!`); don't do this!

What if `results` has no mapping for the `"contents"` key?

What if `results` has a mapping for the `"contents"` key but it isn't a `String`?

What if `results` has a mapping for the `"contents"` key, and it is a `String`, but it's not valid Base 64 encoded data? In this case, NSData's initialization will fail, and return nil.